# Are functions in Rust first class objects?

Tags: rust

Can functions be passed as arguments? For example, in JavaScript you can pass a function as an argument like this:

```
setInterval(function() { /*...*/ }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 19):

They are first class. In contrast to JavaScript, Rust has two types - functions and closures.

```
fn first_class() {
    println!("function");
}

fn higher_kinded<F: FnOnce()>(cb: F) {
    cb();
}

fn main() {
    higher_kinded(first_class); // passing function
    higher_kinded(|| println!("closure")); // passing closure
}
```

Comment: What does the call to `FnOnce()` in the `<>` do? Are the `<>` like Java generics?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question correctly. There is no call to FnOncle. Text in <> are type parametes. fn higher_kinded is generic function in many ways similar to C++ template function or Java generics. The type parameters is then called F and its type is FnOnce() which is type definition for callable objects.

Comment: For those coming to Rust from JavaScript, the `||` does not mean [Logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR), instead it starts defining a [closure](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-01-closures.html) which takes no arguments (for completeness, Rust does have [Logical OR](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/appendix-02-operators.html) too)

Answer (score 13):

Anonymous functions like `function() {}` in JavaScript do exist in Rust, and you can define them using the closure syntax

```
|arg, arg2, arg3| {
  /* function body including optionally closed-over variables */
}
```

Notice that the argument and return types are inferred!

Whether they are first class or not demands a little more exploration. 
By default, closed-over variables will be borrowed by the function. You can specify that those values be moved into the function using a `move` closure:

```
let num = 5;
let plus_num = move |x: i32| x + num;
```

Importantly, closures that do not reference their environment, which includes `move` closures, do not require references to the stack frame that created them. Since their sizes aren't known, they aren't first class objects by themselves.

You can `Box` a closure and return it as a trait object of the [`Fn` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html).

This answer a brief summary of what's in [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/closures.html) which explains how closures are desugared and how they interact with the environment.

Comment: just a heads up that the link doesn't exist anymore

Comment: Updated to reference the new book & new closure syntax/rules (from wow - 2 years ago)

Comment: So... that's a "yes" then?

Comment: @OrangeDog hopefully not being too flippant, but I tried to show it means that fixed sized trait objects are first class.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is the case, as [described](http://doc.rust-lang.org/rust.html#function-types) in the reference manual.

```
fn add(x: int, y: int) -> int {
  return x + y;
}

let mut x = add(5,7);

type Binop<'a> = |int,int|: 'a -> int;
let bo: Binop = add;
x = bo(5,7);
```

It also tried the following, which pass a closure and function in the same way:

```
fn myproc(val: int) {
    println!("{}", val*10);
}

fn call_func(func: |int| -> ()) {
    func(3);
}

…
call_func(|x| {println!("{}", x)});
call_func(myproc);
```

Comment: Link is dead now :(

Comment: @OrangeDog Is [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/functions.html) what you were looking for? Or [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/type-aliases.html)? I know it may be useless for you now, but I'm just wondering what link we can put in the question now.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin Perhaps the internet archive can help? http://web.archive.org/web/20140723015310/http://doc.rust-lang.org/rust.html#function-types