# Differences between `fn` and `||` in type for an array of functions

Tags: rust

I was doing some simple experiments in Rust, involving an array of functions, and finally came out with this working code:

```rust
fn fun1(arg: &String) -> String {
    let prefix = String::from_str("a: ");
    prefix.add(arg)
}

fn fun2(arg: &String) -> String {
    let prefix = String::from_str("b: ");
    prefix.add(arg)
}

fn doall(arg: &String, funcs_vec: &[fn(&String) -> String]) {
    for f in funcs_vec.iter() {
        println!("{}", (*f)(arg));
    }
}

static funcs: &'static [fn(&String) -> String] = &[fun1, fun2];

fn main() {
    doall(&String::from_str("foo"), funcs);
}
```

which prints:

```
a: foo
b: foo
```

Then, reading [some other question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24972394/are-functions-in-rust-first-class-objects), I saw the syntax `|&String| -> String` that should work as well, but trying it like this :

```
fn doall(arg: &String, funcs_vec: &[|&String| -> String]) {
    for f in funcs_vec.iter() {
        println!("{}", (*f)(arg));
    }
}

static funcs: &'static [|&String| -> String] = &[fun1, fun2];
```

Compiler complains with:

```
funcarray.rs:17:25: 17:45 error: missing lifetime specifier
funcarray.rs:17 static funcs: &'static [|& String| -> String] = &[fun1, fun2];
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

If I try to change the line to this:

```
static funcs: &'static [|&String|: 'static -> String] = &[fun1, fun2];
```

it gives me this error :

```
funcarray.rs:17:57: 17:70 error: mismatched types:
    expected `&'static ['static |&collections::string::String| -> collections::string::String:'static]`
    but found `&'static [fn(&collections::string::String) -> collections::string::String]`
(expected fn but found extern fn)
funcarray.rs:17 static funcs: &'static [|&String|: 'static -> String] = &[fun1, fun2];
                                                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

And here I'm pretty lost. What can I do to make it work (if it is possible) ?

And more generally, what are the differences between these two syntaxes for specifying the type of the functions in this array ? It seems to involve lifetimes, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A function pointer and a closure are quite different in Rust.

[The Periodic Table of Rust Types](http://cosmic.mearie.org/2014/01/periodic-table-of-rust-types/) lists

```
|T…| -> U
fn(T…) -> U
```

as `Closure with mutable environment` and `Bare function type`.

A closure captures its environment, a function does not.

A closure cannot be passed *upwards* in the call stack, because the lifetime of the captured environment cannot be specified/validated, a functions does not capture anything and can therefore be *returned*.

We do not *yet* (there has been discussion) have a short syntax to write non-capturing closures, ie. anonymous functions.

As you see, there is a significant semantic and syntactic difference between these and they're not interchangeable.

Interesting blog articles to read about closures and functions in Rust are [Fn Types in Rust, Take 3](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2013/10/10/fn-types-in-rust/) and [Closures and the Borrow Checker](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2014/02/04/closures-and-the-borrow-checker/).

Comment: Nitpick: functions can be used in place of a closure, but not vice versa. `fn twice(f: ||) { (f)(); (f)() }` can accept both a function and closure with compatible signature.

Comment: @A.B. Yes, that's what leaded me into trying to build an array of closures to store functions...

Comment: Shouldn't it be possible to return moving closures, since _they_ own and destroy the captured resources?

Comment: @Kapichu: I don't think moving closures were a thing when I wrote this answer. :S

Comment: I know but now it is :)