# Why do I get an "expected one of 8 possible tokens" error when adding a trait bound that a generic type is a function?

Tags: rust

What is wrong with this code?

```
fn launch_thread<T>(_transform: T)
where
    T: fn(&String) -> String,
{
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3a6d4ffaa1cb24e86b586bbc8b329442)

When I introduce the `where` clause, it stops working:

```
error: expected one of `!`, `(`, `,`, `?`, `for`, `{`, lifetime, or path, found keyword `fn`
 --> src/lib.rs:3:8
  |
3 |     T: fn(&String) -> String,
  |        ^^ expected one of 8 possible tokens
```

Comment: `fn` is the keyword and the type, you are referring to `std::ops::Fn`, or just `Fn`. `where T: Fn(&String) -> String + Send + 'static` will work.

Comment: @user2722968 , well it says in the docs: `This trait (Fn) is not to be confused with function pointers (fn).` , and what I want to do is to exactly that: *pass a function pointer*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Differences between \`fn\` and \`||\` in type for an array of functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24979454/differences-between-fn-and-in-type-for-an-array-of-functions) TL;DR If you want to use function references, you can do that: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=24176c7856346ba35cf871744b64f47f

Comment: @Boiethios great link, but no, it doesn't answer. This is something with `where` syntax. Because if you uncomment the commented code block, everything is going to work.

Comment: @Nulik `fn` isn't a trait, so there is no point to use it as a where clause.

Comment: @Boiethios , now everything is clear.